# Show submit button on textarea edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, textarea

I have a `textarea` and a `button`. I want the button to appear if the text in the textarea is edited. Not on focussed but on edit test. Is this possible in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<textarea id="t_area" rows="3">444</textarea>
<button id="btn" style="display:none">Save</button>
```

Script

```
$('#t_area').on('keyup',function() {
    $('#btn').show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m72Z3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `.change()` event of the textarea to show the button. At its simplest:

```
$('#textarea').change(function() {
    $('#button').show();
});
```

Modify the element ID selectors to suit your code.